# MySQL - str_to_date() not working in update query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform some calculations and update the table with the calculated value using SQL query. The query used is as follows:

```
    UPDATE `table1` pv inner join 
(SELECT  Email,IF(`DS Start Date` = "-",Round((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(`Start Date`,'%Y-%m-%d')))/365,2),
         Round((DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(`DS Start Date`,'%Y-%m-%d'),STR_TO_DATE(`Start Date`,'%Y-%m-%d')))/365,2)) as ba_tenure,
    IF(`DS End Date` != "-",Round((DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(`DS End Date`,'%Y-%m-%d'),STR_TO_DATE(`DS Start Date`,'%Y-%m-%d')))/365,2),
    Round((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(`DS Start Date`,'%Y-%m-%d')))/365,2)) as ds_tenure,
    Round((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(`Start Date`,'%Y-%m-%d')))/365,2) as overall_tenure
                      from `table1` where Status = "Active" ) A on (pv.Email = A.Email)      
                      set  pv.`Tenure (Yrs)` = A.overall_tenure,pv.`BA Team Tenure` = A.ba_tenure,pv.`DS Team Tenure` = A.ds_tenure
```

When I execute the `select` statement, the query runs good. But when I execute the `update` query it throws the error

```
#1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '-' for function str_to_date
```

I cannot figure out the issue. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you create sql fiddle sample?

Answer (score 1):

If your second if you have  `DS Start Date` for true and false but for false this mean that `DS Start Date` is equal to '-'  and this value is not valid for `str_to_date`

```
IF(`DS End Date` != "-",
Round((DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(`DS End Date`,'%Y-%m-%d'),STR_TO_DATE(`DS Start Date`,'%Y-%m-%d')))/365,2),
Round((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(`DS Start Date`,'%Y-%m-%d')))/365,2)) as ds_tenure,
```